# Convert SVG to and from JSON using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, svg

I have created a Cordova Ionic project. I am working on an editor. How can I convert the below SVG content into JSON array and JSON array to SVG content via JavaScript?

```
                <svg width="580" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <!-- Created with Method Draw - http://github.com/duopixel/Method-Draw/ -->
                <g>
                 <title>background</title>
                 <rect fill="#fff" id="canvas_background" height="402" width="582" y="-1" x="-1"/>
                 <g display="none" overflow="visible" y="0" x="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="canvasGrid">
                  <rect fill="url(#gridpattern)" stroke-width="0" y="0" x="0" height="100%" width="100%"/>
                 </g>
                </g>
                <g>
                 <title>Layer 1</title>
                 <rect total-price="129720" data-price="10" id="svg_2" height="69" width="188" y="47" x="63.5" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="none"/>
                 <line total-price="121164.47292" height="75.36667" width="151.66666" data-price="10.6" stroke-linecap="undefined" stroke-linejoin="undefined" id="svg_3" y2="124" x2="470.5" y1="50" x1="319.5" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="none"/>
                 <ellipse total-price="190708.875" height="91.5" width="198.5" data-price="10.5" ry="45" rx="98.5" id="svg_4" cy="323" cx="159" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000" fill="none"/>
                </g>
               </svg>
```

Comment: check 'http://irunmywebsite.com/raphael/SVGTOHTML_LIVE.php' , 'https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-svg' there are bunch of other cli, npm based utilites use..them .

Comment: its not helpful...

Comment: What's wrong in the question? why minus?

Comment: I would transform it to xml and serialize it from xml, since there are built in functions for that.

Comment: See docs on [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer) to get a string representation which you can convert to JSON with JSON.stringify.